# Login after creating a user with formwizard-django

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I would like to login after the creation of users. But i'm using formwizard and I've got an error "global name 'request' is not defined" when i try.

Here is my view.py

```
class ProfilWizard(SessionWizardView):
template_name = "gestionProfil/profil-step1.html"
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render_to_response('gestionProfil/profil.html', {'form_data': form_data})

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    username = form_data[0]['username']
    password = form_data[0]['password']
    email = form_data[0]['email']
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user.first_name = form_data[1]['firstName']
    user.last_name = form_data[1]['lastName']
    user.save()

user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
if user:
    login(request, user)
return form_data
```

So how should i do to login after the creation of users?

Edit :
After making the edit suggested by  user777466 my views.py is now:

```
class ProfilWizard(SessionWizardView):
template_name = "gestionProfil/profil-step1.html"
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    (form_data,user) = process_form_data(form_list)
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    if user:
        login(self.request, user)
        #return HttpResponse(form_data[0]['password'])
        return render_to_response('gestionProfil/profil.html', {'form_data': form_data})

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    username = form_data[0]['username']
    password = form_data[0]['password']
    email = form_data[0]['email']
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user.first_name = form_data[1]['firstName']
    user.last_name = form_data[1]['lastName']
    user.save()

    return (form_data,user)
```

The output during and after the form are :

> [13/Nov/2013 08:39:12] "GET /gestionProfil/createNew/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4639
>
> [13/Nov/2013 08:39:22] "POST /gestionProfil/createNew/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   5085
>
> [13/Nov/2013 08:39:40] "POST /gestionProfil/createNew/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   4601
>
> [13/Nov/2013 08:39:40] "GET
>   /captcha/image/c9adfbd5b6984ed094fdc7c4607acfb4d915d037/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   4611
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:827:
>   RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-11-13
>   08:39:45.847325) while time zone support is active.   RuntimeWarning)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:827:
>   RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-11-13
>   08:39:45.864404) while time zone support is active.   RuntimeWarning)
>
> [13/Nov/2013 08:39:47] "POST /gestionProfil/createNew/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   3704

Edit 2:
 I've remove my database and made a new syncdb, now the authentication is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is not passed through the process_form_data method.

Solution 1 - log the user in the process_form_data method:

```
form_data = process_form_data(self.request, form_list)
def process_form_data(request, form_list)
  ...
```

Solution 2 - log the user in the done method:

```
class ProfilWizard(SessionWizardView):
  template_name = "gestionProfil/profil-step1.html"
  def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
      form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
      user = authenticate(username = form_data[0]['username'], password = form_data[0]['password'])
      if user:
         login(self.request, user)
        return render_to_response('gestionProfil/profil.html', {'form_data': form_data})

  def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    username = form_data[0]['username']
    password = form_data[0]['password']
    email = form_data[0]['email']
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user.first_name = form_data[1]['firstName']
    user.last_name = form_data[1]['lastName']
    user.save()
    return form_data
```

Recently, I had the authenticate() not working on a project because of the password field. In that case, make a simple :

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)
```

So you should have something like:

```
class ProfilWizard(SessionWizardView):
  template_name = "gestionProfil/profil-step1.html"
  def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
      form_data = process_form_data(self.request, form_list)         
      return render_to_response('gestionProfil/profil.html', {'form_data': form_data})

  def process_form_data(self, request, form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    username = form_data[0]['username']
    password = form_data[0]['password']
    email = form_data[0]['email']
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    user.first_name = form_data[1]['firstName']
    user.last_name = form_data[1]['lastName']
    user.save()
    user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    login(request, user)
    return form_data
```

Comment: Thanks, after modifying the code the error disappear. However, it doesn't work. After the creation of the profil they are still not connected. It's like if the authentification did not work.

Comment: can you print the form_data[0]['password']?

Comment: I've tried with the edit but it still doesn't work. When I print form_data[0]['password'] I've got exactly the password that I wrote, not the hash password.

Comment: Can you give some debug output? And maybe try to do the user.backend="" in the done() method, it could be the request that is not passing right.

Comment: I've tried the user.backend="" in the done(). It doesn't change anything. I've got a warning in the output : RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime